# SQL Query to bring back fields that only contain numbers (specifically an IP address)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have quite a few tables with a field called company that can either have in them:

"Fake Company" or "5.5.5.5"

The numerical address above of course being an IP address.

I'm not sure how I'd go about writing a select query that brings back ONLY rows that have an IP address in them and not just text. Any ideas?

Comment: Have in mind that IP address isn't just numbers, it's the DOTs also.

Comment: Why the heck would you have either a companie's name or an IP in your table?

Comment: The information that goes into the DB is reported from many different external IP addresses (most of which we have in a database). When the row is originally inserted it does a lookup to see if we know the IP, if not it just inserts the IP address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use RegularExpressions on SQL-Server, for example:

```
INSERT INTO tIP VALUES('Fake Company');
INSERT INTO tIP VALUES('5.5.5.5');
INSERT INTO tIP VALUES('192.168.5.8');
INSERT INTO tIP VALUES('192.168.5.88');

DECLARE @regexPattern varchar(100);
SET @regexPattern='([0-9]{1,3}\.|\*\.){3}([0-9]{1,3}|\*){1}';

SELECT * FROM tIP 
WHERE dbo.RegexMatch( tIP.IP, @regexPattern ) = 1
```

and here is the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RegexMatch](@Input [nvarchar](4000), @Pattern [nvarchar](4000))
RETURNS [bit] WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [RegexLib].[RegexLib.UserDefinedFunctions].[RegexMatch]
```

- RegularExpressions on SQL-Server:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx
- How to integrate .NET Assemblies in SQL-Server: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DotnetAssembliesInMSSQL.aspx?display=Mobile

Answer (score 3):

A little crude but could this work for you:

```
SELECT ColumnName FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName LIKE '%.%.%.%'
```

Comment: which would also bring `'www.My.Company.com'`

Comment: We don't have any companies with that amount of dots in - that should work I will try it. Thanks very much!

Comment: @ypercube - yes, however, the question states the field can have either "Fake Company" or "5.5.5.5".

Comment: @Barry - yes, however, if you're reading the question as literally as that, then the answer is `SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE company = '5.5.5.5'`.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be to replace the dots and check if the rest is numeric:

```
SELECT ColumnName 
FROM TableName 
WHERE ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(ColumnName, '.', '')) = 1
```

It's not as exact as the RegEx solution, but it's sufficient for distinguishing IP adresses from company names, and maybe it's faster than RegEx or `LIKE '%'`.